# mount point is not a directory

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount a directory from a local desktop in my home network. The computer exporting the nfs share is named `jarvis` and the nfs client is named `marvin`. On marvin, I run `showmount -e jarvis`, and I get:

```
Export list for jarvis:
/exports 192.168.1.0/24
```

I created a folder `/jarvis` on marvin which I would like to be the mount point.

When I try to mount it via `mount -t nfs jarvis:/exports /jarvis`, I get:

```
mount.nfs: mount point /jarvis is not a directory
```

though this is clearly wrong since I just created the directory. How do I mout `jarvis:/exports` to `/jarvis` on marvin so that I can read and write files on marvin but have the be stored on jarvis?

Both computers or using `Kubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /jarvis` on `marvin`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 27 18:46 /jarvis/`

Comment: And `ls -ld /exports` on `jarvis`? Also, what's your kernel version? (`uname -r`)

Comment: `ls -ld /exports` on `jarvis` is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 26 17:10 /exports -> /disk2/nfs_exports/`. Kernel on `jarvis` is `3.16.0-43-generic`, `marvin` it is `3.16.0-44-generic`.

Comment: Here is your problem, `/exports` is a symbolic link, which you can't access by NFS. You should rather use a bind mount on a directory: `sudo mount --bind /disk2/nfs_exports /exports`

Comment: It seems like this might be working, but it takes forever. I run the same `mount -t nfs` command and it just hangs. I am connecting over wifi - how good of a connection do I need to make this work and how do I test it?